# dealing with % symbol in a file using awk command

Tags: unix, awk

I am using this command

```
awk '{printf $1; for (i=2;i<=10;i++) {printf OFS $i} printf "\n"}' FS='|' OFS='|' file.txt >>new_file.txt
```

its working fine if the record does not have any `%` symbol in a file.

My Requirement :

```
Input:
A|B|C|D|E
A|B
Output:
A|B|C|D|E|||||
A|B||||||||
```

Sample value which is giving error - '20% OFF ONLINE PRICE MATCH'

how do I handle this issue?
Error - awk: There are not enough parameters in printf statement |20% OFF ONLINE PRICE MATCH.

Comment: Please add real input data and the real corresponding output to your question.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument to `printf` is actually the format string, which gets printed as-is if there are no formatting flags (`%`*x*) and it's the only argument. Unless you are in control of the string, you should always provide two arguments to printf, exactly for this reason, that is, to guard against formatting flags (expected or otherwise) occurring in the supplied strings. In your case, change the printf statements to

```
printf "%s", $1
```

and

```
printf "%s", OFS $i
```

and you should be fine.

By way of illustration:

```
$ echo '20% OFF ONLINE PRICE MATCH' | awk -F\| '{ printf $1 }'
awk: weird printf conversion % O
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
awk: not enough args in printf(20% OFF ONLINE PRICE MATCH)
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1

$ echo '20% OFF ONLINE PRICE MATCH' | awk -F\| '{ printf "%s\n", $1 }'
20% OFF ONLINE PRICE MATCH
```

Comment: .....After doing mentioned changes, now  script is working exactly as per my requirement. Thanks for prompt response. Really appreciate.